# signal propagates in unequal length (or bended) transmission line

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-circuits, classical-electrodynamics

Suppose I have a square wave signal generated from a signal generator and its outputs are connected to the two terminals of a paired PCB traces (left side of the picture below). The other end of the paired PCB traces are connected to a oscilloscope. V+(I+) and V-(I-) should arrive the red dash line at the same time according to transmission line theory. However, the outer transmission line is longer than the inner transmission line because of the bend, thus, V- travels a longer distance than V+, so should I see a the two signals appears on the oscilloscope in different time with V+ arrives at oscilloscope earlier? I don't think this is right, but I cannot think of a reason why. My gut feelings tell me that the two signal should arrive at oscilloscope at the same time, but I cannot explain it in physics. Can anyone help me to explain it? Thanks[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Obirs.png)

Comment: This question might be better suited for [Electronics.SE].

Comment: thanks @MichaelSeifert, I will try it.